# Delete cookie during redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httprequest, response.redirect

If a request comes in with a certain cookie set, I want to delete that cookie, and redirect back to the same action (and preserve querystring, route values, etc.)

I expect that in the second (redirected) request, the cookie will be gone. *But it isn't.*

My action method:

```
[DeleteCookie]
public virtual ActionResult doStuff() {
  // blah
}
```

My action filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DeleteCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {

    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

    if (request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("foo")) {
      request.Cookies["foo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);     // I tried this
      request.Cookies.Remove("foo");                                  // I tried this
      context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(context.RouteData.Values);
    }

  base.OnActionExecuting(_filterContext);
  }

}
```

During the first request, once I delete the cookie, it disappears from the request. But in the second redirected request, it's still there! And so the code above goes into an infinite loop.

How do I remove it?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cookie from the response object, not the request? The AddYears(-1) should also work on the response object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["foo"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    cookie .Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Comment: The trick was to update the response. That was missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some of the **very important points** related to cookies.

1. We can always add the cookies (**temporary and permanent**).
2. **We can not delete the cookies**, because it will store in client machine and we don't have authority to do the delete operation.

Refer below solution for your reference.

> if (Request.Cookies["userId"] != null)
>
> {
>
> Response.Cookies["userId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
>
> }

Please do the check for cookie exist or not and don't use **Remove** keyword, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing one of the best way, it will help you to understand more., you can do using days also.

It's not very mandatory, you to add year only

> HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["testcookie"];
>
> if (cookie != null)
>
> {
>
> cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.**AddDays**(-1);
>
> Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the cookie to expire and the page to redirect (at least not via MVC).

As explained in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21134768/2068719

I had to expire the cookie, then display a view, and in that view redirect. (In my case I was redirecting back to the same controller action using RedirectToAction.)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Expire";
    Layout = null;
    Response.Redirect( Url.Action("Index", "Home"), false);
}
```